# Gaussian on an oblique ray with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs, draw, gauss

[image]

I try to draw a generic Gaussian over a ray, to indicate a possible generic trend. At the moment I have managed to draw both the ray and the Gaussian, but I can't get it to lay on the ray, as changing the coordinates changes the whole graph. In the image it is as I would like it to look, as it came is in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=100,
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=12cm, 
  width=12cm,
  xtick=thick, 
  ytick=thick,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  ]
\begin{scope}[yshift=-\pgflinewidth]

\clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:6,1);
\addplot [draw=none,fill=lightgray!50!] {gauss(x, 3, 0.8)};
\end{scope}



\addplot [very thick,black!50!] {gauss (x, 3, 0.8)};
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(1,3,0.09)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,3,0.8)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{gauss(1,3,0.8)}

\node[coordinate, pin={Spatial and cognitive distance}] at (axis cs: 3, 0.5){};

\addplot[black!50!, thick](x,x); 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any tips? Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

If you can use a Ti*k*Z picture, it would be very easy. You only have to draw you gaussian function and rotate it.

Like the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% grid
\draw[help lines]  (0,0) grid[step=0.5] (6,6);
% axes
\draw[latex-latex] (0,6) node [above] {$y$} |- (6,0) node [right] {$x$};
% gaussian function
\draw[rotate=45,red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:{6*sqrt(2)},samples=100] (\x,{gauss(\x,{3*sqrt(2)},0.7)});
% line
\draw (0,0) -- (6,6);
% axes labels
\foreach\i in {1,...,5}
{
  \node at (\i,0) [below] {$\i$};
  \node at (0,\i) [left]  {$\i$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much I didn't know about the possibility of rotating the function. Thank again!

Comment: +1: Does the curly bracket syntax **{6*sqrt(2)}** works out of the box?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thanks!! Do you mean without the curly brackets? Yes, it works, I put the curly brackets without thinking, because they are always needed in TikZ coordinates.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that the curly brackets are needed when a calculation is required.